# How do I save data internally to the device?

Tags: java, android, save

I am making an app for tracking four different scores. There is an add and a subtract button for each score, and I want to save as rounds. For example, there would be a file for round 1 with the score from each team, a file for round 2 with the score from each team, etc.

I have been searching YouTube, StackOverflow, and Android Developers for hours trying to find a way I can save data, but none of them make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a model class to hold the score data

```
import java.io.Serializable

data class Round(
    val team1Score: Int,
    val team2Score: Int,
    val team3Score: Int,
    val team4Score: Int,
): Serializable
```

Then let's say you have instances of this `Round` class for each round to hold the score values.

```
val round1 = Round(team1Score = 5, team2Score = 0, team3Score = 9, team4Score = 5)
val round2 = Round(team1Score = 2, team2Score = 10, team3Score = 6, team4Score = 5)
val round3 = Round(team1Score = 4, team2Score = 8, team3Score = 3, team4Score = 1)
```

Then save these objects as `JSON` on files.

```
FileHelper.writeToJsonFile(
    context = getApplicationContext(), 
    data = round1, 
    fileName = "round1"  //if the file doesn't exist, it will be created automatically
) 
FileHelper.writeToJsonFile(
    context = getApplicationContext(), 
    data = round2, 
    fileName = "round2"
)
```

And to read values back

```
val round1 = FileHelper.getFromJsonFile(
    context = getApplicationContext(), 
    fileName = "round1",
    clazz = Round::class //if it doesn't work use Round::class.java
)
```

```
import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import com.google.gson.Gson
import java.io.File

object FileHelper {

    fun writeToJsonFile(context: Application, data: Any, fileName: String) {
        val dataStr = Gson().toJson(data)
        File(context.filesDir, "$fileName.json")
            .writeText(dataStr)
    }

    fun <T> getFromJsonFile(context: Application, fileName: String, clazz: Class<T>): T? {
        return try {
            val data = File(context.filesDir, "$fileName.json").readText()
            Gson().fromJson(data, clazz)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            null
        }
    }

    fun getTextFromResources(context: Context, resId: Int) =
        context.resources.openRawResource(resId).use { inputStream ->
            inputStream.bufferedReader().use {
                it.readText()
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to put each round in a separate file, so I can save more than just the scores?

Comment: @Speedy

The above code already explains how to save scores for each round on separate files. You can see I have saved round1 and round2 score values to two different files `round1.json` and `round2.json`

For example, the code below creates a new file **round1.json**, and saves the round1 object as JSON in it.

`FileHelper.writeToJsonFile(context = getApplicationContext(), data = round1, fileName = "round1");`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a JSON array of the scores for each round, and save the JSON String into a text file.

something like:
`{ "rounds":[{"score_a":10,"score_b":20},{"score_a":30,"score_b":35},{"score_a":24,"score_b":43}]}`

And save it something like this:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = context.openFileOutput("scores.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputStream.write(jsonString.getBytes());
    outputStream.close();
```

And to read it again read the file and make a JSONObject from the String

```
FileInputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput("scores.txt");
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    jsonString = stringBuilder.toString();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray rounds = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rounds");
    //You can use the rounds JSONArray to get individual scorer
    int scoreA = rounds.getJSONObject(0).getInt("score_a");
```